# One-Hot Encoding (OHE) huge corpus for LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm, one-hot-encoding

## Problem

I scraped a huge amount of comments of a popular website for which I'm trying to make a text generator using TensorFlow to build an LSTM architecture. Generally, this is pretty straightforward, but given the size of the data set, I'm running into **memory issues when one-hot encoding the labels**, even when using GCP's AI Platform -- and I'm not too fond of spinning up an expensive job with huge amounts of memory.

I can solve it by limiting:

1. the corpus length
2. the vocabulary size

But I'm trying to make it really good, not settle for less. Otherwise I could just use Markov chains.

## Possible solutions

1. It's common sense that I shouldn't be loading the complete data set into memory. **I'm looking for an equivalent to the ImageDataGenerator, but for text.** I could fit the One-Hot encoder on the complete data set, but transform the data batch by batch. My knowledge of TensorFlow is too limited to get this done properly.
2. Is there a way I can s**tore the OHEd labels in memory, but in a sparse way**?

I have bumped into some threads  of people experiencing the same issues, yet no solutions can be found. Can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code.

## Code

Here's the relevant part in my **task.py**, where I tokenize and one-hot encode.

```
# tokenize corpus
if hparams.trim_corpus != 0:
    corpus = corpus[:hparams.trim_corpus]
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = hparams.n_words_to_keep, oov_token = '<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)

# create input sequences using list of tokens
input_sequences = []
for line in corpus:
    token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([line])[0]
    for i in range(1, len(token_list)):
        n_gram_sequence = token_list[:i+1]
        input_sequences.append(n_gram_sequence)

# pad sequences 
input_sequences = np.array(pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=model.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='pre'))

# Create predictors and label
predictors, labels = input_sequences[:,:-1],input_sequences[:,-1]

# Filter most common words
most_common_items = [item[0] for item in Counter(labels).most_common(hparams.vocab_size)]
indices_to_keep = [True if b in most_common_items else False for b in labels]
predictors = predictors[indices_to_keep]
labels = labels[indices_to_keep]
```

This is the part where things go bad. When I apply the OHE transformation to the training data set, I get memory errors, both locally and in GCP.

```
# Train-test split + encoding
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictors, labels, test_size = 0.2)

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
y_train = enc.transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
y_test = enc.transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', model.serving_input_fn) # What is this?

train_input_fn = lambda: model.input_fn(X_train, y_train, hparams.batch_size, mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
eval_input_fn = lambda: model.input_fn(X_test, y_test, hparams.batch_size, mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL)

train_steps = hparams.num_epochs * len(y_train) / hparams.batch_size

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input_fn, max_steps = train_steps)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn, steps = None, start_delay_secs=10, throttle_secs=10, exporters=exporter)

# Generate Configuration.
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=500)

# Create estimator
estimator = model.keras_estimator(model_dir=hparams.job_dir, config=run_config, learning_rate=hparams.learning_rate, vocab_size=hparams.vocab_size, n_words_to_keep = hparams.n_words_to_keep)

# Start training
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Finally, this is is my model.py.

```
def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size, mode):
    inputs = (features, labels)
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    if mode in (tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT):
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tf.data.TextLineDataset?
This will read in each line from a textfile. After reading each line you can tokenize and one-hot encode.

Example

```
def read_data(fname, batch_size):
   dataset=tf.data.TextLineDataset(fname)
   # Can tokenize and one-hot encode here
   dataset=dataset.batch(batch_size)
   return dataset

data = read_data(fname)
iterator = iter(data)
example = next(iterator)
```